# align two texts in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I am trying to align two texts in the same line in android studio but not able to. I want to align the texts in the center so that output looks like this:

```
       Current balance: 0.00
  Accumulative balance: 0.00
```

As you can see above, `Current balance` is a TextView and `0.00` is another TextView. Same for `Accumulative balance`. I need both lines to be aligned in the center and produce the output above. I tried using `gravity` but when I align it to center the `Current balance` text will be placed on top of the `0.00` text. Can someone help to align two TextViews in same line to produce the output shown above?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap two TextViews in a separate vertically-oriented LinearLayout and align them to the right. Then, place that LinearLayout as a child of the root layout and set `gravity` to `center`. Example:

## WARNING: untested code following

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="end">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Current balance" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.00" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="end">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Accumulative balance" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.00" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thank you so much it works for the balance texts. however, where the i place the text for the 0.00.  current balance and 0.00 are different texts. same for the accum balance.  can you show me how to add 0.00 text next to current balance and accum balance as shown in my original post. thanks

Comment: Wrapping them in separate LinearLayouts and setting `layout_gravity` on them should do the trick. Leaving LinearLayouts without `layout_gravity` attribute and having it on TextViews instead could also work, but I'm not sure. See the updated answer.

Comment: @yoohoo If I answered your question, please use the tick next to my answer to mark it as accepted (and optionally upvote it)